# How to use the Trigger function in SQL to update

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to use the trigger function in SQL when creating a table.

For example - if I insert a new tuple into a table  named Employee that contains values - employee id, employee salary, employee name, employee last name and employee start date.

If I was to enter employee id and salary. But enter null for the other values. I want to create a trigger that intercepts the operation and looks up the salary from the salary table and enters it into the employee salary column for the newly created tuple.

Comment: Hi. It depends over the RDBMS you use. Give us more info please.

Comment: @MauricioKenny MySQL